# Fancy Labels for Tables

Tags: tables

I am trying to draw relational database tables with `tabular`. I would like to label each table with a label at the top left of the table. Neither solution that comes to my mind is exactly what I want.

I would like a rectangular label with the following properties:

- Border width is same as that of table
- Left border aligns with left border of table
- Bottom border overlaps top border of table
- Width is less than column width of table

In the first solution, I use `Tikz` and try to draw the label as a rectangular node. I can never quite get the bottom border of the label to overlap the top border of the table. Nor can I get the left border to align with that of the table.

In the second solution, I use `multicolumn`. This comes very close, the only problem remaining is the width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) {
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|||l|}
\hline
$\texttt{o\_orderkey}$ & $\texttt{o\_orderdate}$ & $\texttt{o\_custkey}$ & rest \\
\hline
0 & 1992-01-01   & 100 & A \\
1 & 1992-01-15   & 3 & B \\ 
200 & 1993-01-01 & 26 & C \\
201 & 1993-01-15 & 42 & D \\
300 & 1994-01-01 & 88 & E \\
301 & 1994-01-01 & 74 & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
};

\node[draw, anchor=south west, inner sep=2pt] at (A.north west) {Table};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|||l|}
\cline{1-1} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Label} \\
\hline
$\texttt{o\_orderkey}$ & $\texttt{o\_orderdate}$ & $\texttt{o\_custkey}$ & rest \\
\hline
0 & 1992-01-01   & 100 & A \\
1 & 1992-01-15   & 3 & B \\ 
200 & 1993-01-01 & 26 & C \\
201 & 1993-01-15 & 42 & D \\
300 & 1994-01-01 & 88 & E \\
301 & 1994-01-01 & 74 & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tables]

Comment: What do you mean with "Width is less than column width of table"? In your second example if you change the line with your multicolumn to ` \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Label} \\ ` you get a rectangle where the borders are the same as the borders of your table.

Comment: For instance, if in the second example, the right border of the label would come before the right border of the first column. Right now, the right border of the label aligns with the right border of the first column.

Comment: What's wrong with using `booktabs` and a simple `Table` that is left justified just as the first column: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{booktabs} \begin{document} \begin{tabular}{*5l} Table \\\toprule $\texttt{o\_orderkey}$ & $\texttt{o\_orderdate}$ & $\texttt{o\_custkey}$ & rest \\ \midrule 0   & 1992-01-01   & 100 & A \\ 1   & 1992-01-15   & 3 & B \\ 200 & 1993-01-01 & 26 & C \\ 201 & 1993-01-15 & 42 & D \\ 300 & 1994-01-01 & 88 & E \\ 301 & 1994-01-01 & 74 & F \\ \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{document}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can box the label and adjust it so that the bottom rule overlaps the first `\hline`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\tablelabel}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{\arrayrulewidth}%
    \hspace{-.5\arrayrulewidth}%
    \fbox{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\strut#1\hspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  }\\[-\arrayrulewidth]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\tablelabel{Label}
\hline
\texttt{o\_orderkey} & \texttt{o\_orderdate} & \texttt{o\_custkey} & rest \\
\hline
  0 & 1992-01-01 & 100 & A \\
  1 & 1992-01-15 &   3 & B \\ 
200 & 1993-01-01 &  26 & C \\
201 & 1993-01-15 &  42 & D \\
300 & 1994-01-01 &  88 & E \\
301 & 1994-01-01 &  74 & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that you don't need `$...$` around `\texttt`.

[image]

You may want a slightly different version that allows for specifying the number of columns to be spanned, in case the label is wider than the first column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\tablelabel}{O{1}m}{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{@{}l@{}}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{\arrayrulewidth}%
    \hspace{-.5\arrayrulewidth}%
    \fbox{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\strut#2\hspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  }\\[-\arrayrulewidth]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\tablelabel[4]{Label}
\hline
\texttt{o\_orderkey} & \texttt{o\_orderdate} & \texttt{o\_custkey} & rest \\
\hline
  0 & 1992-01-01 & 100 & A \\
  1 & 1992-01-15 &   3 & B \\ 
200 & 1993-01-01 &  26 & C \\
201 & 1993-01-15 &  42 & D \\
300 & 1994-01-01 &  88 & E \\
301 & 1994-01-01 &  74 & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `[4]` optional argument in the example is not really necessary, but is used just to show the syntax.

In case you decide to use `booktabs` and avoid vertical rules, which I recommend, a simple modification is needed (no backspace of half the `\arrayrulewidth`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,xparse}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\tablelabel}{O{1}m}{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{@{}l@{}}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{\arrayrulewidth}%
    \fbox{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\strut#2\hspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  }\\[-\arrayrulewidth]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\tablelabel[4]{Label}
\toprule
\texttt{o\_orderkey} & \texttt{o\_orderdate} & \texttt{o\_custkey} & rest \\
\midrule
  0 & 1992-01-01 & 100 & A \\
  1 & 1992-01-15 &   3 & B \\ 
200 & 1993-01-01 &  26 & C \\
201 & 1993-01-15 &  42 & D \\
300 & 1994-01-01 &  88 & E \\
301 & 1994-01-01 &  74 & F \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Update: there needs to be a `%` after the `\setlength{\fboxrule}{\arrayrulewidth}` line. Otherwise the horizontal alignment of the label is not correct. I could not rectify this as an edit, as the edit would be too short.

Answer (score 2):

Is it like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (A) {
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|||l|}
\hline
$\texttt{o\_orderkey}$ & $\texttt{o\_orderdate}$ & $\texttt{o\_custkey}$ & rest \\
\hline
0 & 1992-01-01   & 100 & A \\
1 & 1992-01-15   & 3 & B \\
200 & 1993-01-01 & 26 & C \\
201 & 1993-01-15 & 42 & D \\
300 & 1994-01-01 & 88 & E \\
301 & 1994-01-01 & 74 & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
};

\node[draw, anchor=south west,text depth=0.5ex, inner ysep=2pt,inner xsep=\tabcolsep,outer sep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]A.north west) {Table};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|||l|}
\cline{1-1} Label \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$\texttt{o\_orderkey}$} & $\texttt{o\_orderdate}$ & $\texttt{o\_custkey}$ & rest \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{0} & 1992-01-01   & 100 & A \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{1} & 1992-01-15   & 3 & B \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{200} & 1993-01-01 & 26 & C \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{201} & 1993-01-15 & 42 & D \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{300} & 1994-01-01 & 88 & E \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{301} & 1994-01-01 & 74 & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second solution seems to solve it, but the first is more elegant. Are you sure that in the first solution, the border of the label has the same as the border width of the table? When zooming in, they still don't seem to overlap fully.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Fair enough. I have changed. :)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution, using the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{mine}{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\hskip-0.5\arrayrulewidth\fbox{\space#3\space}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, format = mine, skip =-\arrayrulewidth}
 \caption{Label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|||l|}
\hline
\texttt{o\_orderkey} & \texttt{o\_orderdate} & \texttt{o\_custkey} & rest \\
\hline
0 & 1992-01-01   & 100 & A \\
1 & 1992-01-15   & 3 & B \\
200 & 1993-01-01 & 26 & C \\
201 & 1993-01-15 & 42 & D \\
300 & 1994-01-01 & 88 & E \\
301 & 1994-01-01 & 74 & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. You can use these with Tikz to draw whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{llll}
  table \\
  \hline
  \Block[vlines]{*-*}{}
  \verb|o_orderkey| & \verb|o_orderdate| & \verb|o_custkey| & rest \\
  \hline
  0   & 1992-01-01 & 100 & A \\
  1   & 1992-01-15 & 3   & B \\
  200 & 1993-01-01 & 26  & C \\
  201 & 1993-01-15 & 42  & D \\
  300 & 1994-01-01 & 88  & E \\
  301 & 1994-01-01 & 74  & F \\
  \hline
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \draw (1-|1) -| ([xshift=\tabcolsep]1-1.east) |- (2-|1) -- cycle ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]